# How to Delete Same ID with Same Items only on SQL?

Tags: sql, distinct

I have a Customer Table: Cust

```
 Cust ID CustName
  1         A
  1         B
  2         A
  2         A
  3         A
  3         B
```

And i want to delete the Customer having same Cust ID with same CustName

i've tried using this code:

`WITH CTE AS(SELECT  custnum, custname, BilStAdd, BilCtAdd, Zoneno, cbank_ref,ccelnumber,RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY custnum ORDER BY custnum)FROM cust)`

`DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1`

but it will only delete the Row having the same ID only.

PS: I am just cleaning the database left(like having same id of different customer) by previous database admin and i know it's horrible to leave things like that.
and also I'm dealing with a 10k+ records here

Please help me.

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: Which DBMS and also what do you mean by deleting? Do you mean removing all the records from that specific customer or keeping only a single record and delete other redundant records?

Comment: for the first 2 rows in your sample data, do you want to delete both? for the next 2 rows (those with cust id 2), do you want to delete both or leave one?

Comment: my bad! i've changed my question. im trying to delete the customer with same id and same name only.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to solve my problem by just adding the `custname` inside the `PARTITION` to identify the custid with different custname.

`WITH CTE AS(SELECT  custid, custname,RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY custnum,custname ORDER BY custnum)FROM cust) delete from cte where RN > 1`